# Fetching user name & password to Verify in Grant type "password" using Spring security OAUTH2

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2

I want to extract the username and password from the request so that I can cross verify with a database.

***What I am Trying to achieve***
Extract info username=Test&password=Test@123 from the HTTP  request
 and test it from  DB rather than from the hard coded value in  application.properties.

Currently I am able to achieve that for --user testClient:123456.
please suggest a way to achieve for name and password as well.

```
Http Call :
curl -X POST --user testClient:123456 http://localhost:8090/oauth/token -H "accept: application/json" -H "content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -d "grant_type=password&username=Test&password=Test@123&scope=read_profile"
```

application.properties :

```
**security.user.name=Test
security.user.password=Test@123**
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/oauth
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=validate
```

Auth Server Class

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.configurers.ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableAuthorizationServer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configurers.AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configurers.AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.approval.ApprovalStore;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.approval.JdbcApprovalStore;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.TokenStore;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.JdbcTokenStore;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class OAuth2AuthorizationServer extends
        AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(OAuth2AuthorizationServer.class);


    @Autowired
    AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;


    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Bean
    public TokenStore tokenStore() {
          return new JdbcTokenStore(dataSource);
    }

    @Bean
    public ApprovalStore approvalStore() {
       return new JdbcApprovalStore(dataSource);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints)
            throws Exception {
       endpoints
            .approvalStore(approvalStore())
            .tokenStore(tokenStore())
            // important to add if want to add support the password 
            .authenticationManager(authenticationManager);

    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients)
            throws Exception {
        clients.jdbc(dataSource);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer security) throws Exception {
         security.passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {

        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(4);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using Spring's implemented endpoint `/oauth/token` to get a token. This endpoint is present in `TokenEndpoint` class.

```
 @RequestMapping(
    value = {"/oauth/token"},
    method = {RequestMethod.POST}
)
public ResponseEntity<OAuth2AccessToken> postAccessToken(Principal principal, @RequestParam Map<String, String> parameters) throws HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException {
    if (!(principal instanceof Authentication)) {
        throw new InsufficientAuthenticationException("There is no client authentication. Try adding an appropriate authentication filter.");
    } else {
```

This endpoint takes principal object and a map. Client credentials that you pass as Basic Auth, goes as Principal and other parameters like `grant_type`, `username`, `password`, `scope` etc. goes as map in request parameter.

`OAuth2RequestFactory` takes these parameters and authenticated client information to create a token request. And, then `TokenGranter` takes this token request to grant a token.

These things happen behind the scene, so you dont have do explicitly extract user information for the request.

Comment: Is there is a way by which I can test username=Test&password=Test@123 from the request
with a DB to check if the combination is present rather than a hard coded value in application.properies file. That's the reason I was trying to extract the info.

Comment: Thank you vijay  , I just needed to add  custom UserDetailsService  on top of your suggestion.